# How to fix an issue where importing openpyxl prints a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, openpyxl

Importing openpyxl via any IDE or in the command line prints the following:

```
>>>import openpyxl
{'T': 11051, 'H': 7405, 'E': 14279, ' ': 40775, 'P': 1984, 'R': 7686, 'O': 9938, 'J': 375, 'C': 2751, 'G': 2260, 'U': 4089, 'N': 7493, 'B': 2022, 'K': 987, 'F': 2477, 'M': 3812, 'A': 9153, 'D': 4440, 'L': 5285, 'I': 7854, ',': 2628, 'Y': 2938, 'W': 2856, 'S': 7382, '\n': 4852, 'V': 1169, '.': 2731, '-': 322, '/': 28, ':': 36, '2': 25, '5': 15, '0': 19, '1': 94, '[': 97, '#': 2, ']': 94, '9': 16, '7': 7, 'X': 160, '*': 32, '!': 491, '(': 38, ')': 38, '<': 2, '3': 16, '>': 2, "'": 991, 'Z': 35, ';': 393, 'Q': 76, '?': 371, '"': 24, '8': 9, '4': 9, '6': 7, '%': 1, '@': 2, '$': 2}
```

Can't trace why this is happening and ideally would have a silent way to import the package so that no additional information is pushed to the console before predefined prompts are called.

Have tried using multiple IDEs, upgrading the package, uninstalling and reinstalling the package, and resetting the system.

Comment: Do you have a (own) module / file named *openpyxl* inside the folder?

Comment: No I do not, checked all locations and uninstalled openpyxl and tried to import to confirm. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'`

Comment: @C.Grapel: What gives `from openpyxl import load_workbook`

Comment: This is down to something in your environment. At a guess something is printing the sharedStrings contents.

Comment: @CharlieClark this is accurate. I started a new venv and am not getting this issue but I can't locate the file causing the issue in my old env.

Comment: @stovfl importing that module is not giving any issues and operates as expected

Comment: If you start python with the verbose flag you'll see the paths of everything you import.

Comment: @CharlieClark thanks for that, took a few tries but I tracked down the issue with verbose mode, it was a test file called pprint.py in one of the subdirectories. Renaming this file resolves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

By loading python using verbose (-v) mode as suggested in the comments, I was able to identify a test file that was being loaded in place of a regular python package. Changing the name of that test file resolved the unexpected output.

As the output of importing a package with python in verbose mode is quite long, I used powershell and had to manually interrupt the process in order to retain the top portion of the output and track down the unexpected result and preceding lines.